# How to Show Menu items in grid view

Tags: android

How to show menu items in grid view for action bar.by default it displayed in listvew type but how to display in gridview.for file attachment option i want to show action menu items in grid view like wats app.can anyone tell how to show that custom view on action menu item click in android

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **Try this it working fine.**

**Create custom_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
            android:text="Menu1" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image2"
            android:text="Menu2" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image3"
            android:text="Menu3" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image4"
            android:text="Menu4" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image5"
            android:text="Menu5" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image6"
            android:text="Menu6" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

create layout like this or create custom grid view.

**create file res/menu/main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.customactionbar.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menus"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/menu"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

**create file res/anim/grow_from_top.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
    android:fromXScale="0.3" android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.3" android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="0%"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
/>
<alpha
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
/>
</set>
```

**create file res/anim/shrink_from_bottom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="0.3"
    android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="0.3"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="0%"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
/>
<alpha
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
/>
</set>
```

**paste below lines at style.xml**

```
 <style name="Animations" />

<style name="Animations.GrowFromTop">
    <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/grow_from_top</item>
    <item name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/shrink_from_bottom</item>
</style>
```

**create class file PopupHelper.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

public class PopupHelper {

public static PopupWindow newBasicPopupWindow(Context context) {
    final PopupWindow window = new PopupWindow(context);

    // when a touch even happens outside of the window
    // make the window go away
    window.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                window.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    window.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    window.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    window.setTouchable(true);
    window.setFocusable(true);
    window.setOutsideTouchable(true);

    window.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

    return window;
}

/**
 * Displays like a QuickAction from the anchor view.
 * 
 * @param xOffset
 *            offset in the X direction
 * @param yOffset
 *            offset in the Y direction
 */
public static void showLikeQuickAction(PopupWindow window, View root,
        View anchor, WindowManager windowManager, int xOffset, int yOffset) {

    window.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animations_GrowFromTop);

    int[] location = new int[2];
    anchor.getLocationOnScreen(location);

    Rect anchorRect = new Rect(location[0], location[1], location[0]
            + anchor.getWidth(), location[1] + anchor.getHeight());

    root.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    int rootWidth = root.getMeasuredWidth();
    int rootHeight = root.getMeasuredHeight();

    int screenWidth = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int screenHeight = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    int xPos = ((screenWidth - rootWidth) / 2) + xOffset;
    int yPos = anchorRect.top - rootHeight + yOffset;

    window.showAtLocation(anchor, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, xPos, yPos);
}

}
```

**and finally add this code in youractivity.java file**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menus) {
        final View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.menus);
        showPopup(menuItemView);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void showPopup(View view) {
    PopupWindow showPopup = PopupHelper
            .newBasicPopupWindow(getApplicationContext());
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    showPopup.setContentView(popupView);

    showPopup.setWidth(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    showPopup.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    showPopup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animations_GrowFromTop);
    showPopup.showAsDropDown(view);
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir!!!! its work like a charm!!! can i have your Skype id!!! it should be accepted answer..

Comment: for custom gridview in showPopup method only i need to set the adapter and add the items? or any other way

Comment: when clicking on outside view is not closing.can u tell how to close the view.and it should work like toggle button but it's not working

Comment: button click event you want to hide the view just add this line "showPopup.dismiss();"

Answer (score 1):

**create Custom Grid view grid_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/menu_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:contentDescription="@string/images"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/menu_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:textColor="#196fb5"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Create custom_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Change showPopup(View view) method from above code**

```
private void showPopup(View view) {

    String[] menuText = { "Menu1", "Menu2", "Menu3", "Menu4", "Menu5","Menu6" };
    int[] images = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher };
    GridView menuGrid;
    PopupWindow showPopup = PopupHelper
            .newBasicPopupWindow(getApplicationContext());
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    menuGrid = (GridView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);
    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getApplicationContext(), menuText,
            images);
    menuGrid.setAdapter(adapter);
    showPopup.setContentView(popupView);

    showPopup.setWidth(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    showPopup.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    showPopup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animations_GrowFromTop);
    showPopup.showAsDropDown(view);
}
```

**Create an adapter class file CustomGrid.java**

```
package com.example.customactionbar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private String[] menuText;
private int[] images;

public CustomGrid(Context context, String[] menuText, int[] images) {
    this.context = context;
    this.menuText = menuText;
    this.images = images;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        grid = new View(context);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
        TextView menu_text = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.menu_text);
        menu_text.setText(menuText[position]);

        ImageView packageImage = (ImageView) grid
                .findViewById(R.id.menu_image);

        packageImage.setImageResource(images[position]);

    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }
    return grid;
}

}
```

Comment: gridview i have created and able to show with my code.my problem is when touch on outside view is not closing automatically and that menu item also should work like toggle right but its not working like that

Comment: When i click action bar menu icon it show the menu view and again click this icon hide the menu view and also click out side of the menu hide the menu view it working in my device.you can try another device.